# Is it safe to add ._* in gitignore?

Tags: git, macos

I am on a Mac developing an OS X app with some C/C++ code. I recently added some files to my repository and their duplicate files are showing up as `._name`.

I looked up my .gitignore file and it has `.DS_Store` and few other filters but nothing preventing these `._` files.

Is this the right way to add 
`._*` to my gitignore to prevent these irrelevant files going into repo?

Comment: Obviously, as long as you won't want to commit `._*` files.

Comment: Yes but perhaps I missed to mention the point, which was is it likely that he OS X project generates some important files similar to these which also get ignored using this means ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Mac OS, the finder can in some cases create `._` files that hold some Mac OS specific file information. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14980/why-are-dot-underscore-files-created-and-how-can-i-avoid-them for details.

However these are OS specific files, and therefore should not be checked into version control anyway.

So a `._*` line in your gitignore will not *only* ignore your duplicate `._name` files, but the other files it **might** find that match that pattern need not be checked into version control anyway (apart from any files that you create yourself that match `._*`. In that case you could add an exception in the .gitignore).

Other than that, there is nothing to be found of any other file extensions that start with `._`. See e.g.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_formats
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_list_of_filename_extensions_(A%E2%80%93E)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_list_of_filename_extensions_(F%E2%80%93L)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_list_of_filename_extensions_(M%E2%80%93R)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_list_of_filename_extensions_(S%E2%80%93Z)

So yes, it is safe to ignore `._*`.